# WCF WebGet blocked by firewall

Tags: wcf, wcf-data-services

I have a WCF data service with a [WebGet] method. The url sent to the service looks like

```
http://example.com/MyMethod?param='test'
```

But since the parameter is surrounded by single quotes, my firewall is blocking incoming requests saying it is a SQL injection attack attempt.

Encoding the single quotes as %27 does not work either.

Is there a way around having to include single quotes around query parameter values in WCF?

Comment: You should be asking yourself if you need the single quote? If not, why include it? If you are looking for the value of param, depending on your platform, you can get the value even if you dont have the quote

Comment: @Steven WCF is actually not processing the request if I dont use the quote, saying Bad Request - Error in query syntax

Answer (score 0):

You are using `RESTFul` Service.

Ex: If the method some thing like below

```
[OperationContract]
[WebGet(UriTemplate = "{param}")]
void MyMethod(string param);
```

Then you can directly use the `url` like below without single Quotes.

```
http://example.com/MyMethod?param=test
```

OR

```
http://example.com/MyMethod/param=test
```

Comment: Except for me when I dont use quote I get Bad Request - Error in query syntax error. I do not have a UriTemplate set though, not sure if that changes things

Comment: @user1830197, You can try with above code. I guess it should work without changes.

Comment: You are right - WCF Data service requires quote for string parameters. There is no workaround - this is the literal format for string parameters in OData. Is there a easy way to change the firewall settings? Also, if you can write your own custom host, then you can get the parameter without the quotes and append the quotes in the host layer, before you pass it to WCF Data Services.